# How to send Javascript variable value to Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI and exporting grid data to excel, I know the process and it  works fine for me.
Now I want the excel file name to be a date like "12-12-2014.xlsx" although I can get the date value from drop down using Javascript , but I can't send this date value  to my Kendo UI Grid. 
Here is the code , can any one help me please or any other suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedDate ="";
    $("#startDate").change(function (e) {
          selectedDate = $(this).val();
          var  sd = selectedDate.split('/');
          selectedDate = sd[0] + "-" + sd[1] + "-" + sd[2];
          // selectedDate must be the excel file name
        });
</script>
```

Kendo UI grid :

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Futuresteps.Media.Models.PrintMedia>()
     .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
     {
          // some data
     })
     .Excel(excel => excel
               .FileName(selectedDate+".xlsx")
               .Filterable(true) 
              .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "PrintMedias"))  
       )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the date can change you should compute the date when about to export the file to Excel and not in creation time as you do in:

```
.Excel(excel => excel
    .FileName(selectedDate+".xlsx")
    ...  
)
```

You should define an export to excel event handler (`excelExport`) as:

```
excelExport: function(e) {
    var selectedDate = ...
    e.workbook.fileName = selectedDate + ".xslx";
}
```

And it might look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedDate ="";
    $("#startDate").change(function (e) {
        selectedDate = $(this).val();
        var  sd = selectedDate.split('/');
        selectedDate = sd[0] + "-" + sd[1] + "-" + sd[2];
    });

    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.bind("excelExport", function(e) {
        e.workbook.fileName = selectedDate + ".xslx";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you dear OnaBai ,It worked with some changes, I added your code inside change function while you added out of function....thanks